# WP REST API plugin 500 errors?

Tags: rest-api

I just enabled the WP REST API plugin on three of my sites. On two of them I am able to hit the posts endpoint and get the data returned that I am looking for.

On the third I am getting 500 errors when I try to hit `/wp-json` or `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`.

Any idea what would be causing this? I will say the third site has upwards of 500+ posts, where the other two have about 40 each. But why would that affect `/wp-json`?

Comment: A 500 error is your servers way of saying something went wrong but it doesn't know what, you need to do some debugging steps in order to get the actual error message, check your PHP logs, turn on WP_DEBUG, etc etc

Comment: Thanks. Normally I would, but the problem site is not mine. I have very limited access. Anyway, I figured it out--they are still running WP 4.4. I'm hoping an update fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use custom permalink in your wordpress, please update permalink option.

Any way you can use this url `?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts`

Comment: I voted this up, but when I tried it on my problem site, it didn't work. The result of ?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts is identical to ?rest_route=/wp/v2

Comment: although /wp-json/ and ?rest_route=/ are technically synonymous, you need pretty links enabled in order to use wp-json (i.e. its possible to have you server configured so that wp-json won't work but ?rest_route=/ will). I have seen some rare examples where the converse appears to be true, however this is likely to be highly bespoke server configuration rather than WordPress default behaviour